# iOS Issue with White Space after Leaving App

Tags: ios, grafana

we have the following Setup:
iPad 9th Gen with iPadOS 17.3
Were using Grafana as a WebApp in version 10.1.2

Our flow of actions that leads to the problem is:
Open the Grafana WebApp, make a screen shot using the swipe gesture, draw something in the screenshot, open the annotated screenshot in the Apple Notes app. Add some text notes. Exit the Notes App either using the home button (slight me consistent ind repoducing the error) or through the top left menu.

After these steps we often get the result show in the picture.

Screenshot of Error:

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Its fixed by leaving the `Grafana` WepApp and opening it again, but that's not ideal.

It might be interesting, that the width of the white space is exactly 540px, leaving the remaining width to be exactly `iPads` portrait mode width.

We tried many things related to the viewport and display with in `Grafanas` HTML/CSS Code, but to no avail. These changes only changed, how the content is displayed when the described issue arises. Since the white space also covers the top bar, hiding the battery information, we assume it's not related to Safari directly, but a more general iOS problem.

We would be very thankful for any help.